# how to match 'space' symbol (and only space) in python2 regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use Python v2 (2.7.5 specifically) and the 're' module for regex matching. My problem is that for my application I need to match the 'space' symbol (i.e. 0x20 in hex) and ONLY that symbol as part of the match string. The first thing I tried for that was '\s' and that does not work because it also matches the newline, return, tab and form.

The end requirement is to match a string where the first three characters are digits ('\d'), there is a comma (',') and then eight symbols that are either digits ('\d') or spaces (???).

Any suggestions on how to do that? What I have already tried...

```
 C:\Users\jlaird>python
 Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import re
 >>> goodstring = '333,000000 2'
 >>> badstring = '333,000000\t2'
 >>> print badstring
 333,000000      2
 >>> sRegex = '\d\d\d,[\s\d][\s\d][\s\d][\s\d][\s\d][\s\d][\s\d][\s\d]'
 >>> cRegex = re.compile(sRegex)
 >>> cRegex.match(goodstring)
 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023A7A30>
 >>> cRegex.match(badstring)
 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x025E82C0>
 >>>
```

I want 'badstring' to evaluate to None because it has the tab character instead of the space. How can I do this?

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace character; if you want a space, *use a space*.

Comment: Just type an actual space character in your regex.

Comment: You seem to know character classes, \s, space. How did you miss that a space is a character ?

Comment: Too much coffee and new to the python re dialect. After >6 cups in a 4 hour span my brain does weird stuff.

Comment: ++ Long live _coffee !!_

Answer (score 1):

Thanks jonrsharpe...works. It is always something simple that I make complicated. Sorry...

```
>>> sRegex = '\d\d\d,[ \d][ \d][ \d][ \d][ \d][ \d][ \d][ \d]'
>>> cRegex = re.compile(sRegex)
>>> cRegex.match(goodstring)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023A7A30>
>>> cRegex.match(badstring)
>>>
```